# What should I write in my model?

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3

I am very new to rails. I have the follow text field:

```
<%= form_for(@user) do |f| %> <div class="field">
  <%= f.text_field :nemail, :placeholder => " First Name" %>   </div> <div class="actions">
  <%= f.submit %>   </div>
<% end %>
```

I would like to take the text entered, place it into the symbol :nemail, and then compare :nemail to @user.email. I have no idea what to write in the model for :nemail, currently just have

```
def loginemail
  end
```

Thanks for any help!

Answer (score 0):

You might want to tell what kind of comparision.
Also, currently your form will go to /users POST and not loginemail. Is that what you want? Your form doesn't really make sense in my opinion. How can you compare a new user's attribute to something that u haven't got yet?

Comparision:

```
def loginemail
   @user = ..
   if params[:nemail] == @user.email
      ..
   else ...
   end
end
```